# Question about one of the axioms of connection from Hilbert's The Foundations of Geometry

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

The axiom is on page 3 and is as follows:
**If two planes α, β have a point A in common, then they have at least a second point B in common**

Then on the same page a theorem is deduced and is as follows:
Theorem 1. Two straight lines of a plane have either one point or no point in
common; **two planes have no point in common or a straight line in commo**n; a
plane and a straight line not lying in it have no point or one point in common.

How can these statements be both true?

Comment: The key is in the "or" part of the second statement. It's not true that two planes can simultaneously have points in common and no points in common, but if they have a straight line in common then they certainly have at least two points in common (given that a straight line is a set of points). Does that answer your question?

Comment: It does, thank you